# How to make shaking animation away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a yellow hover area, when the mouse hovers around this area, event: a tab appear in exactly this hover area. But when I put the mouse there, the tab starts to appear and shaking
But I don't know how to make the shaking error go away

here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#demo').mouseleave(function(event) {
        $('.tab').stop().animate({
            opacity : '0.5',
            marginLeft: '190px', 
      width:'0px'
        }, 600, function() {        //animation complete
            $('#demo').addClass('hovered');
        });
    });
    $('#demo').mouseover(function(event) {
        $('.tab').stop().animate({
            opacity : '1',
            marginLeft: '0px', width:'190px'
        }, 300, function() {        //animation complete
            $('#demo').removeClass('hovered');
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#demo {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
    border: solid 1px #666;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width:190px;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: yellow;
}
#demo.hovered {
    backgound-color: #000;
}
.tab {
    margin-left: 190px;
    width: 0px;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #876;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="demo">Hover here!</button>
<div class="tab">First Panel</div>
```

anyone help me with this? I am a javascript beginner

Answer (score 1):

Instead of firing `mouseleave` event on `#demo`, i fire `mouseleave` event on `.tab`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tab').mouseleave(function(event) {
    $('.tab').stop().animate({
      opacity: '0.5',
      marginLeft: '190px',
      width: '0px'
    }, 600, function() { //animation complete
      $('#demo').addClass('hovered');
    });
  });
  $('#demo').mouseover(function(event) {
    $('.tab').stop().animate({
      opacity: '1',
      marginLeft: '0px',
      width: '190px'
    }, 300, function() { //animation complete
      $('#demo').removeClass('hovered');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#demo {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#demo.hovered {
  backgound-color: #000;
}

.tab {
  margin-left: 190px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #876;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
`
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="demo">Hover here!</button>
<div class="tab">First Panel</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much you save my day

Answer (score 1):

it's because you trigger the hover only on the yellow rectangle and when the tab appears you stop hover the yellow rectangle. In my solution, you need to trigger the `mouseleave()` event also on the `.tab`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#demo').mouseleave(function(event) {
    $('.tab').mouseleave(function(event) { //add this line
      $('.tab').stop().animate({
        opacity: '0.5',
        marginLeft: '190px',
        width: '0px'
      }, 600, function() { //animation complete
        $('#demo').addClass('hovered');
      });
    });  //add this line
  });
  $('#demo').mouseover(function(event) {
      $('.tab').stop().animate({
        opacity: '1',
        marginLeft: '0px',
        width: '190px'
      }, 300, function() { //animation complete
        $('#demo').removeClass('hovered');
      });
    });
});
```

```css
#demo {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  border: solid 1px #666;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#demo.hovered {
  backgound-color: #000;
}

.tab {
  margin-left: 190px;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: #876;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
`
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="demo">Hover here!</button>
<div class="tab">First Panel</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want any user interaction on the tab?

If not, then I would add `pointer-events: none;` property to your `.tab` class.

Then the `mouseleave` event won't trigger, but you wouldn't be able to use any mouse events inside your `tab` element.